# A combinatorics problem dealing with injective functions

Tags: combinatorics, functions

I'm trying to solve this combinatorics problem:

> If $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$, $B=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $f:A\to B$ is an injective mapping satisfying **$f(i)≠i$ for all i∈A**, then the number of such mappings are:

I thought of a logic like total one function combination we first figure out and we have to subtract something from that. But what is that "something" is what I'm not being able to pick up.

Could some please give a hint or advice or a quickie on this one. Thanks!

EDIT: This question was asked in the JEE Mains exam a few years back and it involves a very good application of the inclusion and exclusion principle. Just saying as I was asked to edit this (by some jobless dude who wants badges) by providing more context and why it would be useful to you guys.

Comment: there are $6$ choices for $F(1)$, then $5$ choices for $F(2)$ and so on.  At the end, subtract $1$ to remove the identity function.

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  I guessed that, by writing $f(i)\neq I$ you were just excluding the identity function, but that's just a guess.  What you actually wrote doesn't appear to mean anything in particular.

Comment: Does $f(i)≠I$ mean that $f(i)\not=i$ for all $i\in A$? Or $f(i)\not=i$ for at least one $i\in A$?

Comment: @RobertZ Yes I edited.

Comment: @RobertZ Please do upvote too if now appreciate the question

Comment: @lulu Edited dude

Comment: In that case, my first comment was correct.

Comment: @lulu wait what??? What do you get as the final result? I dont think your comment is correct

Comment: Oh, my mistake.  I was sticking with my (incorrect) guess.  I would proceed with Inclusion Exclusion.

Comment: @lulu No probs brother. Also do upvote if you now find the beauty in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inclusion Exclusion is useful here.  There are $6\times 5\times 4\times 3=360$ injective functions if you ignore the restriction.

Now, let's remove those that fix one specified value.  If, say, $f(1)=1$ then there are $5\times 4\times 3=60$ injective functions.  As there are $4$ values that might be fixed, we must subtract $4\times 60=240$.

Now we must add back those that fix two specified points.  There are $6$ ways to pick the two fixed points, and then there are $4\times 3=12$ ways to assign the other two values.  Thus we add back $6\times 12=72$

And now we subtract those that fix three specified points.  There are $4$ ways to choose the three fixed points, and then $3$ ways to assign the extra value.  Thus we subtract $4\times 3=12$.

And finally we add back the unique map that fixes all $4$ points.

In the end we get $$360-240+72-12+1=\boxed {181}$$

Comment: Hey brother, can you explain the intention of this line : "Now we must add back those that fix two specified points. There are 6
 ways to pick the two fixed points, and then there are 4×3=12
 ways to assign the other two values. Thus we add back 6×12=72." Like why do we add back those 2 fixed points...and which fixed points exactly?

Comment: This is [Inclusion Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).  the idea is that you first ignore the restriction, then you subtract off those that fix a single value.  But having done that, you  see that you subtracted those which fixed two points twice, so you have to add those back, but then you have to subtract those which fix three.  It's a powerful counting technique...takes a while to get used to, but a good tool.